# Insert into SQL server from Regular Expression returned text

Tags: regex, t-sql, insert, backreference

In SQL Server 2008, I have built a regex match and replace function from below code project site and is working well.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/SqlRegEx.aspx?msg=3683405#xx3683405xx.
This functions basically looks up column text, finds match and replaces with the replaced text. I have used back reference here.

e.g. if Column1 had 'the first article #345 is refered by 9999 and place in 001', it will return
345#9999#001

The select statement 
Select column1, dbo.ufn_RegExReplace(Column1, '(?\d+).*?(?\d+).*?(?\d+).*?(?\d+)', '${First_number_match}#${Second_number_match}#Third_number_match',1) is working fine.

What I want is to insert 345#9999#001 into three columns of a table.

Please note, in the my actual problem, I will have to use Regular Expression. I simplified for experts to focus on the issue.

As we know Regex are nerve-racking and using with SQL adds to it. So I will appreciate any help on this.
Thanks for your time to read this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to split `345#9999#001` into three parts and insert each part into a different column? Or do you want the complete string in each of the three columns?

Comment: From what I understand of the functions described on your link, you should use the function ufn_RegExSplit instead of ufn_RegExReplace

Comment: Patrick Echterbruch: Yes your assumption is correct. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a string split function and use that to get your individual values.  For example, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_StringSplit(@String NVARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter NCHAR(1))       
RETURNS @tblItems TABLE (item NVARCHAR(8000))       
AS       
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @idx INT       
    DECLARE @slice NVARCHAR(8000)       

    SELECT @idx = 1       
        IF LEN(@String) < 1 OR @String IS NULL  RETURN       

    WHILE (@idx != 0 AND LEN(@string) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)       
        IF @idx != 0       
            SET @slice = LEFT(@String, @idx - 1)       
        ELSE       
            SET @slice = @String       

        IF(LEN(@slice) > 0)  
            INSERT INTO @tblItems(item) VALUES (@slice)       

        -- Trim saved item from remaining string 
        SET @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @idx)             
    END
RETURN       
END
```

Alternatively, you could modify the above Split function to return your 3 values in a single table row if desired, or as 3 output parameters on a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks nybbler, this can work for the example I described. But the actual scenario, text has to be extracted with Regular Expression. I simplified the example though.